# Seat Reservation (Change color when submit)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to ask some question...I'm want to make seat reservation which when user submit their selected seat..the table data will change color into red...Help..

```
<tr id="place">
<td width="50px" height="45px" bgcolor=lightgreen>
<input type="checkbox" name="seatNumber[]" value="A04" onclick="return KeepCount()" id="size"/><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A04</td>

<td width="50px" height="45px" bgcolor=lightgreen>
<input type="checkbox" name="seatNumber[]" value="A05" onclick="return KeepCount()" id="size"/><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A05</td>
<td width="50px" height="45px" ></td> 

<tr id="place">
<td width="50px" height="45px" bgcolor=lightgreen>
<input type="checkbox" name="seatNumber[]" value="A08" OnClick="return KeepCount()" id="size"/><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A08</td
```

Comment: The page gets refreshed on input click?

Comment: provide the html code

Comment: yes something like that...

Comment: Are you saying you want the colours to change immediately when the user clicks, or when the page refreshes after the submission?

Comment: ....from what i understand, you want to display the red color after user submit... just compare the posted value with the checkbox value then highlight with diff color, did not see how difficult this is...

Comment: What about using a prebuild jquery plugin rather than reinventing the whole wheel See demo at http://jsc.mm-lamp.com/
and source at https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts

Comment: Is the form posted using AJAX or is it submitted in the normal way?